# Typo3 - extending page/content element editing details with custom fields

Tags: typo3, field, editing

I would like to know if there is some way to extend Typo3 page or content element editing fields with some custom fields.

To make an example, I would like to insert a single date field in the page editing layout, beside to Title, Alternative Navigation Title and so on. Is that possibile without making new dce content elements?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is possible by extending the so-called `TCA`. Have a look at these examples https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html . In your case, you'll want to extend the table `pages`.

Comment: Thank you, Jonas. Now is clear. Your comment was very helpful. I try it

Comment: There are many ways, one of them, which  is part of TYPO3 since... forever (and most common) is - as Jonas pointed extending it with a custom extension. Another easy approach that requires less programming skills is using the [Mask extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask) or DCE which you already mentioned. Which one you'll use is up to you, sometimes it's good to use mix of these.

Comment: Your comments, guys, are very helpful.  Thank you very much! This will change a lot for me in making the backend experience handier.